# Swift 3 - How to use JSON Array in custom Tabbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, tabbar

I am fresher in iOS Development.I am using Tabman for Tab like layout.I want to populate tabbar items with my json array.

my json:-

```
{
"ManagerName": null,
"ManagerCellNo": null,
"DayDescrList": [
    {
        "DaySeq": 1,
        "Descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda. ",
        "DescrSeq": 1,
        "HotelId": 1,
        "HotelNm": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "DaySeq": 2,
        "Descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.",
        "DescrSeq": 1,
        "HotelId": 1,
        "HotelNm": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "DaySeq": 3,
        "Descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.",
        "DescrSeq": 1,
        "HotelId": 2,
        "HotelNm": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "DaySeq": 4,
        "Descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.",
        "DescrSeq": 1,
        "HotelId": 3,
        "HotelNm": "ABC"
    }
]
```

I want to use 'DayDescrList's 'DaySeq' as my tabbar items.
I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

what i am trying in code:-

```
 func alamoget() {

    Alamofire.request("URL").responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) in

        if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {

            let swiftyJSONVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let resData = swiftyJSONVar["DayDescrList"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
        }

    })
}
func viewControllers(forPageboyViewController pageboyViewController: PageboyViewController) -> [UIViewController]? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main)
    var dict = arrRes[(targetIndex)!]
    var viewControllers = [UIViewController] ()
    var tabBarItems : [TabmanBar.Item] = []
    for i in 0 ..< dict["DaySeq"] {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "childvc") as! childvc
        vc.index = i+1

        tabBarItems.append(Item(title: String(format: "Day %i",vc.index!)))
        viewControllers.append(vc)
    }
    self.bar.items = tabBarItems
    return viewControllers

}
```

My `viewDidLoad()` Method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    alamoget()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.bar.location = .top
}
```

Please Help me

Comment: And where is the problem? Something is not working or you don't know the next steps after receiving the JSON?

Comment: @Woof yaa i don't know the next steps after receiving the JSON

Comment: When your arrRes did set with values from the URL and you sure that the data inside are correct  (print to be sure), the you need to reload view controllers by calling func viewControllers(forPageboyViewController pageboyViewController: PageboyViewController) -> [UIViewController]?  I don't see the code when you are setting viewControllers var for the  Tabbar

Comment: @Woof see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not enough code to get how you are using the datasource, but anyway

We need to reload tabs right after new data received:

```
var arrRes: [[String:AnyObject]] = [] {
    didSet{
        reloadTabs()
    }
}

func reloadTabs(){
    //if you have an additionl datasource array, we will prepare a new
    guard let controllers = viewControllers(forPageboyViewController: YourPageboyViewController) else{
        return
    }

    //then we need to reload bars in the main queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
        self?.reloadPages()
    }
}
```

If the method viewControllers(forPageboyViewController pageboyViewController: PageboyViewController) is using as a data sourse, just add reloadPages() inside the alamofire completion and you don't need to add any other code:

```
func alamoget() {

    Alamofire.request("URL").responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) in

        if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {

            let swiftyJSONVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let resData = swiftyJSONVar["DayDescrList"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
                    self.reloadPages()
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```